# Variable has different value depending on the function calling it

Tags: c++, algorithm, variables, search

I'm writing a c++ program to attempt to emulate batch scripts. Currently I'm attempting to implement a variable system. I have the system all set up so that every time the user creates a new variable, it is added to a vector as the name of the variable, a comma, and then the value. I have some algorithms set up to split the string by delimiter (comma) and return a vector with the first entry being the name, and the second being the value. When using these algorithms to print the name, the name of the variable is successfully printed (in this case, "test"). however, attempting to use this same variable in a linear search algorithm, the variable is "test,123" instead of just "test". Below is the code that is causing this error.

```
std::string hugeStr=std::string(strSplitter(std::string(removeChar(std::string(splitCommand[1]), '\%')), ",")[0]);
std::cout<<hugeStr<<std::endl<<std::endl;
int result=linearSearch(varVector, varVector.size(), hugeStr);
std::cout<<result<<std::endl;
```

Below is the search algorithm.

```
int linearSearch(std::vector<std::string> myVec, int size, std::string searchKey)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(searchKey==std::string(myVec[i]))
            return i;
        else{
            std::cout<<myVec[i]<<std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

When the user initializes a variable (in this case, with the name of "test", and the value of "123"), the first cout statement prints "test". However, the `cout` statement in the linear search algorithm prints "test,123" and returns -1. Why does the variable have a different value when passed to the search algorithm?

A full copy of the code can be found at the [github repo](https://github.com/kookerus/batch-interpreter) if it's needed.

Comment: What on earth is going on with all those `std::string(...)` temporaries?

Comment: Take a look at `std::map`. Or `std::unordered_map`. Or at least `std::pair`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. You're outputting the value of the first element in your vector, not the searchKey you passed into it.

You do realize that this loop will never get to i==1, right? No matter what, it's going to return while checking the myVec[0].